# MapServer stopped showing maps on a website

Tags: mapserver, linux

I have a MapServer version 7* installed on Linux, to serve maps to a website. It worked well until recently, but now it's not serving maps anymore and can't figure out why.
When I check `ps aux`, the `mapserv` service seeems to be running, the webpage requests are valid and are sent out as they should, and the data that mapserver uses - the maps - have stayed the same.

I wanted to login to MapServer but now, there is another problem - MapServer apparently has a password, which I did not get when I took over the project. Password is lost, but is needed to restart the service afaik. **Is there any way to recover the password?
How do I fix the issue with MapServer not serving maps?**

*It's an old project I took over, legacy code, that's why we kept the 7.4.4 version, or else everything would have to be changed.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.  The user account running mapserv doesn't have permissions to see the data.  Did a user account get deleted perhaps.  You should be able to change permissions using sudo.

Comment: User account has not changed, mapserver had ben serving maps prior to this just fine. Sudden change does not come from changed code, permissions, even updated. It has been all the same, up and running, until that point when maps just stopped showing up.

Comment: To the maps show up when making the request locally, outside of the web application?

Comment: I found the error, it's "msLoadMap(): Unable to access file." which does seem like a permission issue, since the files do exist. Local request works, however the files also have all r & x permissions enabled.

Comment: EDIT: I found the error, it's "msLoadMap(): Unable to access file." which does seem like a permission issue, since the files do exist. Local request (edit) is refused. Files have all r & x permissions enabled. When I make local request it says: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: I also checked:
>$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep :80 (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

But I'm not sure how to interpret this. State is LISTEN, but no appliation is listening??